# PHP web scraper with post request for pagination

Tags: php, web-scraping, curl, http-post

I have a site "https://www.hellowork.mhlw.go.jp/kensaku/GECA110010.do?action=initDisp&screenId=GECA110010"

it a japanese site that give list of job table with paginatio and each pagination require to submit a form again and the site always has cookie with JSESSIONID

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtR4Y.png)

you have to click this button to get the data

i got the data of the first page only and i tried everything that I think off and could not get the data of others page

plzz help

this is the code that gives the data of first page

```
echo "woking";
$mainUrl = "https://www.hellowork.mhlw.go.jp/kensaku/GECA110010.do";


// first parameter for sending request
$firstParam = array(
    'kSNoJo'=>  '',
    'kSNoGe'=>  '',
    'kjKbnRadioBtn'=>  1,
    'nenreiInput'=>  '',
    'tDFK1CmbBox'=>  '',
    'tDFK2CmbBox'=>  '',
    'tDFK3CmbBox'=>  '',
    'sKGYBRUIJo1'=> '' ,
    'sKGYBRUIGe1'=> '' ,
    'sKGYBRUIJo2'=> '' ,
    'sKGYBRUIGe2'=> '' ,
    'sKGYBRUIJo3'=> '' ,
    'sKGYBRUIGe3'=> '' ,
    'freeWordInput'=> '' ,
    'nOTKNSKFreeWordInput'=> '' ,
    'searchBtn'=> '検索',
    'kJNoJo1'=> '' ,
    'kJNoGe1'=> '' ,
    'kJNoJo2'=> '' ,
    'kJNoGe2'=> '' ,
    'kJNoJo3'=> '' ,
    'kJNoGe3'=> '' ,
    'fwListNaviDisp'=> 30,
    'kJNoJo4'=> '' ,
    'kJNoGe4'=> '' ,
    'kJNoJo5'=> '' ,
    'kJNoGe5'=> '' ,
    'jGSHNoJo'=> '' ,
    'jGSHNoChuu'=> '' ,
    'jGSHNoGe'=> '' ,
    'kyujinkensu'=>  0,
    'iNFTeikyoRiyoDantaiID'=> '',
    'fwListNaviBtn4'=> 4,
    'searchClear'=>  0,
    'siku1Hidden'=>  '',
    'siku2Hidden'=>  '',
    'siku3Hidden'=>  '',
    'kiboSuruSKSU1Hidden'=>  '',
    'kiboSuruSKSU2Hidden'=>  '',
    'kiboSuruSKSU3Hidden'=>  '',
    'summaryDisp'=>  false,
    'searchInitDisp'=>  0,
    'screenId'=>  'GECA110010',
    'action'=>  '',
    'codeAssistType'=>  '',
    'codeAssistKind'=>  '',
    'codeAssistCode'=>  '',
    'codeAssistItemCode'=>  '',
    'codeAssistItemName'=>  '',
    'codeAssistDivide'=>  '',
    'maba_vrbs'=> 'infTkRiyoDantaiBtn,searchShosaiBtn,searchBtn,searchNoBtn,searchClearBtn,dispDetailBtn,kyujinhyoBtn',
    'preCheckFlg'=>  false,
);

//this is the parameter 
$nextPageParam = array(
    'kSNoJo'=> '',
    'kSNoGe'=> '',
    'kjKbnRadioBtn'=> 1,
    'nenreiInput'=> '',
    'tDFK1CmbBox'=> '',
    'tDFK2CmbBox'=> '',
    'tDFK3CmbBox'=> '',
    'sKGYBRUIJo1'=> '',
    'sKGYBRUIGe1'=> '',
    'sKGYBRUIJo2'=> '',
    'sKGYBRUIGe2'=> '',
    'sKGYBRUIJo3'=> '',
    'sKGYBRUIGe3'=> '',
    'freeWordInput'=> '',
    'nOTKNSKFreeWordInput'=> '',
    'searchBtn'=> '検索',
    'kJNoJo1'=> '',
    'kJNoGe1'=> '',
    'kJNoJo2'=> '',
    'kJNoGe2'=> '',
    'kJNoJo3'=> '',
    'kJNoGe3'=> '',
    'kJNoJo4'=> '',
    'kJNoGe4'=> '',
    'kJNoJo5'=> '',
    'kJNoGe5'=> '',
    'jGSHNoJo'=> '',
    'jGSHNoChuu'=> '',
    'jGSHNoGe'=> '',
    'kyujinkensu'=> '0',
    'fwListNaviSortTop'=> 1,
    'fwListNaviDispTop'=> 30,
    'fwListNaviBtn1'=> '',
    'fwListNaviBtn2'=> '',
    'fwListNaviBtn3'=> '',
    'fwListNaviBtn4'=> 4,
    'fwListNaviBtn5'=> '',
    'fwListNaviBtn6'=> '',
    'fwListNaviSortBtm'=> 1,
    'fwListNaviDispBtm'=> 30,
    'fwListNowPage'=> 1,
    'fwListLeftPage'=> 1,
    'fwListNaviCount'=> 7,
    'fwListNaviDisp'=> 30,
    'fwListNaviSort'=> 1,
    'iNFTeikyoRiyoDantaiID'=> '',
    'searchClear'=> 0,
    'siku1Hidden'=> '',
    'siku2Hidden'=> '',
    'siku3Hidden'=> '',
    'kiboSuruSKSU1Hidden'=> '',
    'kiboSuruSKSU2Hidden'=> '',
    'kiboSuruSKSU3Hidden'=> '',
    'summaryDisp'=> true,
    'searchInitDisp'=> 1,
    'screenId'=> 'GECA110010',
    'action'=> '',
    'codeAssistType'=> '',
    'codeAssistKind'=> '',
    'codeAssistCode'=> '',
    'codeAssistItemCode'=> '',
    'codeAssistItemName'=> '',
    'codeAssistDivide'=> '',
    'maba_vrbs'=> 'infTkRiyoDantaiBtn,searchShosaiBtn,searchBtn,searchNoBtn,searchClearBtn,dispDetailBtn,kyujinhyoBtn',
    'preCheckFlg'=> false,
);


$sendParam = http_build_query($firstParam); // generate URL-encoded query string
$nextPage = http_build_query($nextPageParam); // generate URL-encoded query string

$cookies = array(); // to store the cookie data that we get from the response

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mainUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sendParam); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'readCookie'); // get the cookie data for readCookie function
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies['set-cookie']); // send the cookie data

echo "<pre>";
$html = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nextPage);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'readCookie');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies['set-cookie']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);

echo $html;

// set the current the cookie data to $cookies array
function readCookie($curl, $header) {
    global $cookies;
    $len = strlen($header);
    $header = explode(':', $header, 2);
    if (count($header) < 2) // ignore invalid headers
        return $len;

    $name = strtolower(trim($header[0]));
    if ($name == 'set-cookie') {
        $parts = explode(';', $header[1]);
        $value = trim($parts[0]);
        $cookies[$name] = $value;
    }
    return $len;
}
```

Comment: Just use your browser's network tools and compare the payloads when you click the pagination buttons. When I do that, at a quick glance it appears that something that starts with `fwListNaviBtn` holds the page. The left-most numeric button is `fwListNaviBtn1`, the right-most is `fwListNaviBtn7`, and in between are 2 through 5. I'm guessing the specific number isn't relevant, they're just trying 1 through 7 probably.

Comment: I have already tried that, as you can see that in array $nextPageParam I have set the key 'fwListNaviBtn4'=> 4, but it only show the content of first page.